# Python is not ending in a new computer

Tags: python, multithreading, image

I've a complex code using multithread that works fine in two computers (w10 both, python 3.10), but when I use part of the code used to create PNG images the code is not working in the new computer.

I've checked and both have the same python packages.  The Run log is exactly the same but in one case I get:

> Finishing time: 2023-03-08 17:24:14.609495 Time taken: 0:00:18.974656
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

and the other one **never ends**...  seems that some threads are not ending and don't know why if the code is exactly the same.  **Any idea?**

I attach the code that executes the multithread.

```
 def run_strategy_parallel(self):
        """Run the strategy for multiple tickers using multiple threads."""
        self.input_data_handler.download_stock_data_parallel()

        tickers = self.input_data_handler.get_tickers_list()
        start_time = datetime.now()
        print(f"{40*'='}\nStarting time: {start_time}\n{40*'-'}")
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results = executor.map(self._process_strategy_wrapper, tickers)

        self._write_output(df=pd.concat(results))

        timer_end = datetime.now()
        print(f"{40*'-'}\nFinishing time: {timer_end}")
        print(f"Time taken: {timer_end - start_time}")

    def _process_strategy_wrapper(self, ticker) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """Wrapper to catch and print exceptions from the strategy."""
        try:
            return self._process_strategy(ticker=ticker)
        except Exception as e:
            print(80*"=")
            print(f"Error processing strategy for ticker: {ticker}")
            print(80*"-")
            traceback.print_exception(e)

    def _process_strategy(self, ticker: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        df_stock = self.input_data_handler.get_stock_data(ticker=ticker)
        if df_stock is None:
            print(f"No stock data available for {ticker}. Skipping...")
            return pd.DataFrame()

        df_buy = self.buy_signal_finder.run(
            ticker=ticker,
            stock_data=df_stock,
        )

        df_sell = self.sell_signal_finder.run(
            ticker=ticker,
            stock_data=df_stock,
        )

        return pd.concat([df_buy, df_sell])
```

Comment: Without a [mre] I don't think it's possible to help you. Please read [ask] and the [tour] as well, and see if you can edit this post to include the minimum amount of info needed for us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Not asking for a solution, but for ideas on what could happen between  2 computers where with the very same code one does multithread prorperly and the other don't.  I used python interpreter 3.10 in both

Comment: `Not asking for a solution, but for ideas` huh? That's not the point of this site. Regardless, there's still not enough info here to even guess. If you want people to throw out guesses with almost zero information, then this post is far too open-ended for this site. This is a Q&A site where your questions are required to be objective and not open-ended. Answers are also supposed to be objective and not just vague guesses. Answers can only be as specific as you were in writing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Python was not able to end some of the threads due to two reasons.  Thanks to a pm of a user I've found both.

As far as I used the same code, same w10 version, same python interpreter and also same packages a user helped me asking to check **package versions because are a common reason to have threads not ending.**

The newest version of kaleido is a bit buggy and an older version worked fine.  The other reason (and off-topic) is that backslashes and fwdslashes work different in each windows even when they are both same language and same version... very weird, but a replace did the job.